# JQuery: replace and close open tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to divide the content of an element in divs. The delimiter is `<hr/>` and all open tags should be closed before the closing-div and (if needed) reopened after the reopened div tag. My naive idea was to traverse with jQuery through an elements children, replace all occurrences of `<hr/>` with `</div><div>` and close all open tags (up to a certain level) before that. I don't know how to reopen them though.

Example:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Bla some text
    <hr/>
    Some more text
    </p>
</div>
```

will become:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <p>Bla some text
        </p>
    </div><div>
        <p>Some more text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I had in mind was to simply visit each tag in their order of appearance, add them to a stack when they open, remove them when they're closed again, if I find a delimiter, close all tags in the stack (but don't remove them), insert the `<div/>` tag, reopen all tags on the stack in reverse order. continue until end and close all still open tags.

The purpose of this is to chunk a text into predefined parts. It is for a text pagination and the divs are the pages. I want the user to be able to manually specify the break, even inside of ul's, p's and so on.

Any help is appreciated.